# Magento 2 - How can I import / export the admin users from M2 to M2?

Tags: magento2, admin, migration

I'm using two Magento 2, I'd like to transfer the admin users to another install, how could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your admin users data are on the tables **admin_user** and **admin_passwords**, you can use these commands to export and import:

**Export**

```
mysqldump -p --user=username dbname admin_user admin_passwords > myAdminUsers.sql
```

**Import**

```
mysql -u username -p -D dbname < myAdminUsers.sql
```

> **Important**
>
> If you use a database prefix, don't forget to use on these commands above.

Answer (score 1):

As of Magento 2.3, these are the important tables to note when exporting admin users: `admin_user, admin_passwords, authorization_role`

Export:

```
mysqldump -u username -p --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false magento2_db admin_user admin_passwords authorization_role | gzip > magento2_db_admin_user.sql.gz
```

Import:

```
zcat magento2_db_admin_user.sql.gz | mysql -u username -p magento2_db
```

Comment: Just bricked my admins and integrations doing this. 

Would not recommend to a friend.